# AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

вот код. он должен открывать фф, заходить на сайт и вводить в поле логина указанный текст

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://xss.is')

xpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[1]/div/dl[1]/dd/input'

element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
element.send_keys("deda")

input("Нажмите Enter, чтобы закрыть...")
```

Выдает такую ошибку:

```
File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\sel.py.txt", line 9, in <module>
  element = browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath'
```

Comment: Какие версии Firefox и selenium вы используете?